# How to decode JSON javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, json

I'm newbie on Phonegap and Javascript. I'm trying to develop login example for android. I send username and password with Post Method to php file and get this json encoded output

```
{"tag":"login","success":"1","error":"0"},"name":"can","email":"can@can.com"}}
```

Here is my client side code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <div style="padding:3px 2px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc">Ajax Form</div> 
    <form id="ff" action="http://mehmetcantas.info/ogdtek/balance/index.php" method="post">

<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td>username : <input id="email" name="email" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password : <input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="tag" value="login"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AffiliateLink : <input id="AffiliateLink" name="AffiliateLink" type="text"></td>
</tr>


<tr><td><input value="Submit" type="submit"></td>

</tr></tbody></table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ff').form({ 
    success:function(data){ 
        $.messager.alert('Info', data, 'info'); 
    } 

});
</script>
```

I want to do if succes:1 then open welcome.html

Comment: You mean you want to navigate to `welcome.html` if success is `1`?

Comment: @plalx yes. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
if (data.succes == '1') {
   window.location="welcome.html";
}
else {
   window.location="login.html";
}
```

PS: The json you provided is not valid.

```
{"tag":"login","success":"1","error":"0"},"name":"can","email":"can@can.com"}}
```

IT should be as below.

```
{"tag":"login","success":"1","error":"0","name":"can","email":"can@can.com"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Purus Actually exact json : `{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"527bd9c46997e5.99994053","user":{"name":"can","email":"can","created_at":"2013-11-07 20:19:48","updated_at":null,"userid":"2","oauth":"5288e80b16b4d5.90905559"}}`
I dont know Where will i add your suggestion after succes: ?

Comment: The above code should go inside your success call.

Comment: It still shows the output. Thank you. I give up, I cant do it